# Excel VBA Button Copy WorkSheet to New Word Doc

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, worksheet

The code below copies a table I have in a work sheet and pastes it in a new Microsoft Word Document. The only issue is it cuts off half the table when pasted in the word document. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
Sub btnExport()
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Range("C2:D60").Copy

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.14")
With objWord
    .Documents.Add
    .Visible = True
    .Selection.Paste
End With
End Sub
```

[Sheet I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFUna.png)

Comment: Can you give an example of the data you are copying?  Also, which half is cut off?  Do you lose the bottom of the table, or does the second column run off the right hand side of the page?

Comment: The Second column runs off the right hand side of the page.

Comment: Have you considered using Landscape mode instead of Portrait in Word?  Or is the table too large even then?  You only have two columns - just how large is the data in each column?  Can you provide an example of the data in use?

Comment: Just uploaded a pic of the sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Word `AutoFit` command to make the table fit into the document.  I've included code to swap the orientation to Landscape as well but this may not be necessary.

```
Sub btnExport()
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Range("C2:D60").Copy ' you should name the worksheet as well here really

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application.14")
    With objWord
        .Documents.Add
        .ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = 1 'wdOrientLandscape
        .Visible = True
        .Selection.Paste
        .ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Method or data member not found error .Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow

Comment: Oops.  Tables is a collections belonging to a `Document` object - edited.